# Reflection calls to Methods with Primitive parameters, using the wrapper class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm currently working on a project, whereby I need to make requests to methods that I don't know the parameter types of at compile time, and they are being resolved at run time. Until now, it has been working fine, but I've just run into a bit of a speed bump.

**The Problem**

The issue I'm facing is actually frustratingly simple. I'm attempting to call `JTextField.setVisible()`. As we know, `setVisible` takes one parameter of type `boolean`. My code resolves some XML, and returns an object of type `Boolean`. When attempting to call this method with the `boolean` wrapper object, I am receiving a `NoSuchMethodException` because it is failing to map `Boolean` to `boolean`, when resolving the method.

**My Question**

Is there a way of resolving the primitive type at run time, and passing that class in, in place of the wrapper class?

**My code**

Firstly, some user input is parsed. This user input is then filtered through the following method, that converts the `String` input into an `Object` output:

```
 /**
 * Converts a string value to it's appropriate primitive value.
 *
 * @param input the string value usually taken from the XML.
 * @return the object representing the value in the string.
 */
public static Object toPrimitive(String input) {
    if (input.matches(Constants.INTEGER_PATTERN)) {
        return new Integer(input);
    } else if (input.matches(Constants.DOUBLE_PATTERN)) {
        return new Double(input);
    } else if (input.matches(Constants.BOOLEAN_PATTERN)) {
        return new Boolean(input);
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

This is then eventually propagated to the following method, that attempts to resolve the setter:

```
// Cycle through each value and populate instance with it, assuming a setter.
String setterName = toSetter(key);
Object value = namedParameter.get(key); // Value returned from method.

// Execute the setter, adding the value to the object.
Method setter = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(setterName, value.getClass());
setter.invoke(instance, value);
```

And at the line `setter.invoke(instance, value)`, I am receiving the `NoSuchMethodException`. Is there a solution available for this?

**My attempts at a solution**

I had the idea of writing a method to map the wrapper class to the primitive class, which now looks like this:

```
/**
 * Converts a wrapper class to it's primitive type.
 * @param type
 * @return
 */
public static Class wrapperToPrimitiveClass(Class type) {
    if(isPrimitive(type)) {
        if(type == Integer.class) {
            return int.class;
        }
        else if(type == Double.class) {
            return double.class;
        }
        else if(type == Character.class) {
            return char.class;
        }
        else if(type == Byte.class) {
            return byte.class;
        }
        else if(type == Boolean.class) {
            return boolean.class;
        }
        else if(type == Float.class) {
            return float.class;
        }
        else if(type == Long.class) {
            return long.class;
        }
        else {
            return short.class;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, I still receive the same message, only this time it is claiming that the method does not exist, even with the `boolean` type. Now, I know this is false because this will compile fine:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();

field.setVisible(true);
```

However, when attempting to make the same call via reflection, I still receive the error.

**Error Message**

When attempting with the wrapper class, I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.swing.JTextField.setVisible(java.lang.Boolean)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2004)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.populateWithSetters(ParamFactory.java:366)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParametersAsObject(ParamFactory.java:333)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParameter(ParamFactory.java:64)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParametersAsList(ParamFactory.java:125)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParameter(ParamFactory.java:58)
at com.block.executor.impl.Executor.executeBlockReference(Executor.java:135)
at com.block.executor.impl.Executor.execute(Executor.java:51)
at com.block.program.Blocks.execute(Blocks.java:49)
at com.block.program.StartUp.main(StartUp.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

And when attempting with the primitive, I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.swing.JTextField.setVisible(boolean)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2004)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.populateWithSetters(ParamFactory.java:373)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParametersAsObject(ParamFactory.java:339)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParameter(ParamFactory.java:64)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParametersAsList(ParamFactory.java:125)
at com.block.executor.impl.ParamFactory.getParameter(ParamFactory.java:58)
at com.block.executor.impl.Executor.executeBlockReference(Executor.java:135)
at com.block.executor.impl.Executor.execute(Executor.java:51)
at com.block.program.Blocks.execute(Blocks.java:49)
at com.block.program.StartUp.main(StartUp.java:24)
```

Comment: Your immediate problem is that `setVisible()` is *declared* by `JComponent`, not `JTextField`. Aside from that, have you looked at [java.beans.Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)?

Comment: That looks promising. I may actually overhaul my method resolution with an `Introspector`. Give me a day or two to get to grips with it, and if I can implement a working solution using it I'll let you know. In the mean time, could you please make an answer out of this so I can vote up and mark as correct when I know more?